# "Reconstruction theorem" auf Deutsch

Tags: translation, mathematics

Ich suche das richtige deutsche Wort für das englische „Reconstruction“ im englischen mathematischen Ausdruck „Reconstruction theorem“. Ich denke „Wiederherstellungstheorem“ kingt nicht so geeignet, oder?

---

I'm looking for the correct German translation of the mathematical expression "reconstruction theorem".

Comment: Seit wann ist es in der höheren Mathematik üblich Fach-Termini zu übersetzen (Seit wir nicht mehr führend sind ?).

Comment: Es gibt fuer Namen von Theoremen keine kanonischen Uebersetzungen. Ich nehme an du brauchst die Uebersetzung fuer ein bestimmtes? Hast du einen (englische) Referenz? Ansonsten hier ist ein Beispiel fuer einen "Rekonstruktionssatz": http://mo.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/inhalt/aussage/aussage836/

Comment: Ja, letztendlich scheint es um Spektralzerlegungen zu gehen? Hier ein anderes Beispiel aus der mathematischen Physik/QM: http://techmath.uibk.ac.at/wagner/psfiles/Quanten.pdf

Comment: @JorgeCampos: Ja, "Satz" kommt deutlich haeufiger vor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wenn es keinen feststehenden deutschen Begriff für das Theorem gibt (in Wikipedia oder deutschem Fachbuch nachsehen), dann würde ich das sehr nahe am englischen Original übersetzen, also "Rekonstruktionstheorem".  Dann erkennt jeder, der das Original kennt, was damit gemeint ist.

**Nachtrag:** "Rekonstruktionssatz" scheint richtig zu sein (siehe Kommentare oben). Allgemein kann man Theorem meistens mit Satz übersetzen.

Answer (score -1):

Im deutschen Sprachraum sind die mathematischen Bedingungen und Zusammenhänge, die für das Sampeln analoger Signal und die Rekonstruktion des gesampelten Signals gelten, als

**Nyquist-Shannon-Abtasttheorem**
oder kurz als

### Abtasttheorem

bekannt.

Dabei geht es darum ein Signal, das ursprünglich in analoger Form vorliegt (z.B. ein Geräusch oder das Licht, das von einer zu fotografierenden Szenerie ausgeht) zu digitalisieren (mit einem digitalen Audio-Recorder oder einer Digital-Kamera).

Das zu tun ist keine große Hexerei, schwierig wird es aber bei der Rekonstruktion des analogen Signals aus den digitalen Daten. Das originale Signal kann nur in bestimmten Fällen verlustfrei rekonstruiert werden. Im Allgemeinen gehen schon beim Abtasten (also dem Digitalisieren) Informationen unwiederbringlich verloren, die sich später nie wieder rekonstruieren lassen.

Diese mathematischen Zusammenhänge zwischen dem Abtasten und dem Rekonstruieren heißen im Englischen "offiziell" - ähnlich wie im Deutschen **Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem** oder kurz **sampling theorem**.

Wenn aber der Vorgang der Rekonstruktion besonders hervorgehoben werden soll, spricht man auch vom **Rekonstruktions-Satz** (engl: *reconstruction theorem*)